# 2.79: Only some grass(Hair) particles showing up in render?

Tags: particles

I am making a sword in stone thing and when I got to the grass, everything looked fine. However, when I clicked render, only some of the grass would show up

[image: Object View][image: Rendered View]

[image: Settings]

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a file with this particle system? You can use this service https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Crantisz The file is too large apparently

Comment: Remove all data except ground plane

Comment: @Crantisz It is done. I has to lower the particle count. It should be 100000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have child simplification, turn it off.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, why is this option on by default?